# Passing parameters to route not found - Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-activatedroute

Defining the Route in my app-routing :

`{ path: 'user/:id', component: UserDetailComponent },`

Defining the Navigation

`<a [routerLink]="['/user', user.id]">detail</a>`

In UserDetailComponent

`this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];`

Firstly. I get user detail, but when I refresh page (userdetail/:id) I get this message error

[image: Error message when I refresh page user detail /user/:id]

Comment: You angular app is not loading xD

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the UserDetailComponent you need in the beginning of the NgOnInit you need to define this:

```
 const urlInfo = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
 this.getDetails(urlInfo) //in this function you subscribe to the api call
```

Comment: I tried it. Same problem

Comment: Can you make for us stackblitz example?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed the slash position... In your routing code, you have a slash separating users from the id, just change the code from this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', user.id]">detail</a>
```

To this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['user/', user.id]">detail</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having `base="/user"` in your `index.html` or something else while you need it to be `base="/"` (assuming you are doing plain `npm ng serve`)